# INotifyPropertyChanged With Private Field

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, mvvm

i want to implement PropertyChanged event but idk how to use it in this scenario

```
class ParentClass
{
    private ChildClass _childClass = new ChildClass();

    //How to detect that the underlying _childClass.Name value changed ? so it changed             this.
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _childClass.Name; }
    }

    public void EditChild()
    {
        _childClass.Name = "SOME VALUE";
    }
}

class ChildClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your question is not very detailed and you did not explain why or if you need only to expose that one property or not, there is a different approach that may work for you:

Instead of exposing the one single property, expose your whole Child class and bind it directly in your XAML code

```
class ParentClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ChildClass _childClass = new ChildClass();

    public ChildClass ChildClass
    {
        get { return _childClass; }
        set { 
            if(_childClass != value) {
                OnPropertyChanged("ChildClass");
                // This one is necessary so that the ChildOfChildClass property/binding gets updated accordingly
                OnPropertyChanged("ChildOfChildClass");
            }
        }
    }

    public ChildClass ChildOfChildClass
    {
        get { return (_childClass!=null)?_childClass.Child:null; }
    }

    public void EditChild()
    {
        _childClass.Name = "SOME VALUE";
    }

    // Implament PropertyChanged handling in Parent class too
    ...
}
```

This way the changes of the `ChildClass` will be directly propagated to the XAML/UI. Since your child class implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` it works perfectly fine.

**Edit:** 
Like the edit above. Though you'll need to update your `ParentClass` Properties to add setters and also implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, so that the UI gets notified when ChildClass changes, like in the above example.

Comment: Sorry if my question lacks some detils, But what if the ChildClass contains another child class and i want to expose it's child as a property in the ParentClass ?

Comment: NOTE:  IAM WORKING IN WINFORMS

Comment: Basically you can do databindings in WinForms too, but its more difficult and has to be done in Code. Personally I've done Bindings only in WPF since it was designed with bindings in mind. Check out MSDN Documentation on how to do WinForms bindings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: For some reason the event isn't fired idk know why...

Comment: Could be due to your usage of `CallerMemberName` Attribute. I prefer usage of Expression Trees instead of string or `CallerMemberName`. Check out http://www.devvblog.com/?p=27 for example of using Expression Trees as it works better with refactoring and gives more control on triggering the Change event